# Creating new site collection in Office 365 from an APP

Tags: sharepoint, office365, office365-apps

I have a requirement to create a new site collection from within an App in Office 365 programmatically.  What I mean by a new site collection, is that after creation, it should appear on the list of site collections under the Admin --> Sharepoint tab of Office 365. I tried using a similar code below within a sharepoint hosted app that i had created,

```
//create sp context and get root
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var rootWeb = clientContext.site.rootWeb();
this.clientContext.load(rootWeb);
this.clientContext.executeQUery();

//set web info
var webInfo = new SP.WebCreationInformation();
webInfo.set_webTemplate('YourTemplateName');
webInfo.set_description('Your site description');
webInfo.set_title('Your site tittle');
webInfo.set_url(siteUrl);
webInfo.set_language(yourLangCode);
this.rootWeb.get_webs().add(webInfo);
this.rootWeb.update();

// save site and set callbacks
this.clientContext.load(this.rootWeb);
this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnSiteCreationSuccess),
Function.createDelegate(this, this.Error));
```

However this just creates a sub site under the site collection that hosts my App.

Any suggestions on how i could implement this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done with SharePoint Object Model 2013, the functions you need are inside the assembly: Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll, which is located at C:\Program Files\SharePoint Client Components\Assemblies after you install the SharePoint Client Object model 2013.

There's not much doc on this, but [SharePoint Online Management Shell](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/sharepoint-help/introduction-to-the-sharepoint-online-management-shell-HA102915057.aspx) has the command to create the site collection, so I think it can be done with C# and figured it out. The code snippet shows how to do it.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Security;

namespace SharePoint123
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //please change the value of user name, password, and admin portal URL
            string username = "xxxx@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com";
            String pwd = "xxxx";
            ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://xxxx-admin.sharepoint.com");
            SecureString password = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in pwd.ToCharArray())
            {
                password.AppendChar(c);
            }
            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, password);

            Tenant t = new Tenant(context);
            context.ExecuteQuery();//login into SharePoint online


            //code to create a new site collection
            var newsite = new SiteCreationProperties()
            {
                Url = "https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/createdbyProgram1",
                Owner = "xxxxx@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
                Template = "STS#0", //using the team site template, check the MSDN if you want to use other template
                StorageMaximumLevel = 100,
                UserCodeMaximumLevel = 100,
                UserCodeWarningLevel = 100,
                StorageWarningLevel = 300,
                Title = "CreatedbyPrgram",
                CompatibilityLevel = 15, //15 means Shapoint online 2013, 14 means Sharepoint online 2010

            };
            t.CreateSite(newsite);

            context.ExecuteQuery();
            //end 

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that Matt. That's exactly what I was looking for. Its unbelievable how hard it is to get documentation on it. Do you know whether it is possible to assign permissions for a user or a group programmatically to the new site collection created?

Comment: I think it is possible, because it is already in the powershell command:http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161371(v=office.15) . It should be donw with this class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.user.aspx. But I don't have an example for this.