# Create SharePoint Site Collection Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint-2010

I've been attempting to create a site collection from a custom web service I have built in C#. I already had some methods in this that ran some powershell commands so I figured I would just create the site using powershell commands like the code below. This code runs fine without error but does not create a site collection, seems as if it is doing nothing. Is there a better way or can someone see what may be wrong below?

```
public string CreateSiteCollection(string urlroot, string urlname, string database, string primaryadmin, string secondadmin, string language, string description, string title, string template)
    {

        //Find language and template code 
        string lang_code = get_lang_code(language);
        string temp_code = get_temp_code(template);

        Call the PowerShell.Create() method to create an empty pipeline
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();

                // Place our script in the string myscript
        string myscript = string.Format(@"
                        Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -erroraction 'silentlycontinue'
                        $template = Get-SPWebTemplate ""{0}""
                        New-SPSite {1}{2} -OwnerAlias '{3}' -SecondaryOwnerAlias '{4}' -Language {5} -Description '{6}' -ContentDatabase {7} -Template $template -Name '{8}'
                        ", temp_code, urlroot, urlname, primaryadmin, secondadmin, lang_code, description, database, title);


        // Create PowerShell runspace
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();    
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline(); // create pipepline then feed it myscript
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(myscript);
        pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

        Collection<PSObject> results;
        try
        {
            // Executing the script
            results = pipeline.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // An error occurred, return the exception
            return string.Format("Exception caught: {0}", e);
        }

        runspace.Close();

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PSObject obj in results)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
        }

        string output = stringBuilder.ToString().Trim();
        if (output == "")
        {
            return "PowerShell Commands ran sucessfully with no output";
        }
        else
        {
            return String.Format("PowerShell Commands ran sucessfully and returned the following: {0}", output);
        }
    } // End of CreateSiteColleciton
```

I may use the Admin.asmx web service  instead, but it would be easier if I could get this working because it allows me more customization.

Comment: Please check this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268629/creating-new-site-collection-in-office-365-from-an-app/21285138#21285138

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go the with the object model just because it makes more sense. Below is the code for creating a new site collection:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
     using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://servername:port/"))
     {
          using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
          {
               HttpContext.Current = null;
               site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
               web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

               var newSite = site.WebApplication.Sites.Add(....);
          }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you can't call the SharePoint server side object model directly from your web service like this, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms411953(v=office.14).aspx.

Or is there a requirement to go through a set of CmdLets?

Comment: I have attempted this a few times without much luck. I get some permission based errors that I don't really have too much time to debug now, but I'm thinking I might have to try this route again when I have more time.